how to insert to postgresql with dynamic values
i want to select some oracle tables then insert into postgresql
here is code:
//foreach Ora_sql_select in oracle tables 
import (    
    "context"
    "database/sql/driver"
    "fmt"
    "io"
    "os"
    "reflect"
    "strconv"
    "strings"
    "github.com/jackc/pgx/v5"
    go_ora "github.com/sijms/go-ora/v2"
)
connPg, err := pgx.Connect(context.Background(), "postgres://postgres:pgroot@localhost:5432/abcd")

stmt := go_ora.NewStmt(Ora_sql_select, connOra)
        defer stmt.Close()
        rows, err := stmt.Query(nil)        
        defer rows.Close()
        columns := rows.Columns()
        values := make([]driver.Value, len(columns))        
        for {
            err = rows.Next(values)
            if err != nil {
                break
            }
            for i, c := range values {
                fmt.Printf("%s: %v\n", columns[i], c)
            }
//how to convert values to dynamic struct then exec to postgresql?
            var tmpa, tmpb = connPg.Exec(context.Background(), Pg_sql_insert, values...)
            fmt.Println(tmpa)
            fmt.Println(tmpb)
            Record(columns, values)
        }

how to convert values to dynamic struct then exec to postgresql?
cannot find any useful code in github

What is connPg? How is it created? What Go package? Also: you probably need so-called prepared statement which uses positional parameters ("placeholders"), is created before the iteration loop and executed (each time with a new set of valies) on each iteration. I do not understand why do you need "dynamic struct" here, for what it worth.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Ora_sql_select and Pg_sql are  dynamic varialble . oracle sql eg:select a,b,c from table1 and Pg_sql_insert is the insert sql eg: insert into table1(a,b,c) values  ($1,$2,$3) and .So  I can't fix the parameter num   or variable.
